# String to name functions or parameters (I don't know how it is)

Tags: string, vector

I'm learning vectors and I want to create a function called "createVector2D", so I have this code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <math.h>

    using namespace std;

    class Vector2D {
    public:
        float x, y;
        Vector2D(float X, float Y)
        {
            x = X;
            y = Y;
        }

        float getMagnitude()
        {
            return sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));
        }
    };

    void createVector (float x, float y, string vectorname){
        Vector2D vectorname(x,y);
        cout<<"Vector created!\nName: "<<vectorname<<"\nx: "<<x<<"\ny:"<<y<<endl;
    }

int main(){
    float x;
    float y;
    string vecname;
    printf ("Vector Velocidad (x,y)\nInserta X\n");
    cin>>x;
    system("cls");
    printf ("Vector Velocidad (%f,y)\nInserta Y\n", x);
    cin>>y;
    system("cls");
    printf ("Vector Velocidad (%f,%f)\n", x, y);
    printf ("Escribe el nombre del vector\n");
    cin>>vecname;
    createVector (x,y,vecname);
    printf ("-1. Calcular Magnitud (Modulo)\n");
    printf ("-2. Enseñar Vector\n");
    int op = 0;
    cin>>op;
    switch(op){
        case 1:
              cout<<vecname.getMagnitude()<<endl;
              break;
        case 2:
              cout<<"x: "<<vecname.x<<endl;  
              cout<<"y: "<<vecname.y<<endl;  
              break;
        default:
              cout<<"No elegiste nada"<<endl;
              break;
    }
    system("pause>NULL");   
}
```

The error is that the string can not works like that, and I don't know how to transform it to works correctly as Vector name of the class Vector2D, anybody knows? :D thanks for read.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have `createVector()` *return a value*:

```
Vector2D createVector(float x, float y)
{
    Vector2D vec(x, y);
    return vec;
}
```

The return value of this function is then assigned to your `vecname` variable:

```
Vector2D vecname;
vecname = createVector(1, 2);
```

But, you don't want such a function anyway, since `Vector2D` already has a public constructor which works just fine:

```
Vector2D vecname(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you cannot do that:

```
void createVector( float x, float y, string vectorname ) {
    Vector2D vectorname( x, y );
    cout << "Vector created!\nName: " << vectorname << "\nx: " << x << "\ny:" << y << endl;
}
```

`vectorname` is a `string` variable and you're attempting to use it like a `Vector2D` variable.

If you want each instanced `Vector2D` to have a name, you'll need to add that data member to the class:

```
class Vector2D {
public:
    float x, y;
    string name;

    Vector2D( float X, float Y, string vectorname ) {
        x = X;
        y = Y;
        name = vectorname;
        cout << "Hello, I'm " << name << "at:\nx: " << x << "\ny: " << y << endl;
    }

    ~Vector2D() {
        cout << name << " signing off!\n";
    }

    float getMagnitude() {
        return sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));
    }
};

Vector2D createVector( float x, float y, string vectorname ) {
    return new Vector2D( x, y, vectorname );
}
```